# finding the number of a variable in Object arrays in different classes (java)

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

Presume we have a class Student and a class Activity.

```
class Student {
    private Activity[] myActivites;
    public Activity[] getAct() {
        return this.myActivites
    }
}

class Activity {
    private String name;
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    private Student[] members;

}
```

the members array represents all the students that go to this particular activity, while the myActivites array in Student represents all the different activites the particular student is visiting.

How would I go about writing an INT method in the activity class that returns the number of **differently named** activites that all of the students in this particular activity are visiting (so, two different Activity objects can have the same name!)

EDIT:
Thanks for your concerns guys. It's actually not homework, I'm preparing for a test next week.
Hope you will forgive me for not translating the code into english, as it takes quite some time.
It's a part of a larger program I have to write. So far, I've done something like this:

```
    public int steviloRazlicnihDejavnosti() {
    int najboljPriden = this.clani[0].getSteviloKrozkov();
    for (int i=1; i<this.clani.length; i++) {
        int trenutnaPridnost = this.clani[i].getSteviloKrozkov();
        if (trenutnaPridnost > najboljPriden) {
            najboljPriden = trenutnaPridnost;
        }
    }
    String[][] krozkiClanov = new String[this.clani.length][najboljPriden];
    for (int i=0; i<this.clani.length; i++) {
        Ucenec trenutni = this.clani[i];
        Krozek[] krozkiTrenutnega = trenutni.getKrozki();
        for (int j=0; j<krozkiTrenutnega.length; j++) {
            krozkiClanov[i][j] = krozkiTrenutnega[j].getDejavnost();
        }
    }

    int stevec = 0;
    return;
```

"Krozek" is the class Activity.
"Ucenec" is the class Student.
at first, I figure out, which student has the most activites and then set a 2d string array of this length (and the length of all students), which I fill with the names of the activites. Then, I was thinking of checking the 2D array (haven't written that up yet), but believe that this will take too much time - I basically just prolonged the same problem I was facing before.

Hope this shows that I've actually put some work into this.
I've also tried solving it with adding an extra boolean attribute "HasBeenChecked", and would not count any object that "HasBeenChecked", but figured that this did not help with recodnising the duplicates of the names.

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show some effort at solving your problem, we are not here to write code for you

Comment: Sure thing. Hope it's ok that I didn't translate everything: it takes a lot of effort :).

Comment: What have you tried?  A few hints:  Iterate over each `member` to get **all** of their `Activity`s.  For each member iterate over each `Activity` to get that `Activity` name.  Use a data structure such as a `Set<String>` to keep track of the unique set of `Activity` names.  Return the number of entries in the set.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Set<String>... Is there a way that I could do it using only object arrays?